# Can you alias a host on a user by user basis?

Tags: unix, hosts

On a unix machine, you can alias a host by adding it to /etc/hosts, but this is visible to the whole system.

Is there any similarly simple way to add a hostname to just the users profile?

Comment: What do you want to do with the alias? Is a solution like `ramseyHost=127.0.0.1` and `ping ${ramseyHost}` good enough?

Comment: While that would work for the shell, it wouldn't work for other aspects of the system like /etc/hosts does.  When I alias a host in /etc/hosts, it also means that I can navigate to it in a browser.